# Status of Steinberg UR22 USB audio interface in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound, usb

What's the current status of the Steinberg UR22 USB audio interface in Ubuntu 15.04?  Does it work out-of-the-box as expected, such as being able to record to a stereo track, or does it take some tweaking to get it to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! I've have just purchased one of these and plugged it into my Ubuntu 15.04 box, and was somewhat surprised and relieved to see it appear in the device lists - 2 inputs, 2 outputs and midi in/out!

### I only just got it yesterday, so I've tested the inputs, but not the outputs yet, or the midi (though the midi ports are there in alsa), since I'll need to go shopping for some cables.

Update: I've tested midi and outputs to PC speakers and it seems to be all good.  Using an inductive Mic and it seems quite clear.  Haven't recorded anything yet to look at the amount of noise, but live looping with it seems to work well!